# Dequeing a specific value from a queue?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I have to implement a method that is supposed to do:

```
// int dequeue(queue_t* q, int* number);
```

But I wonder what is the point of second argument since dequeing always takes the last value. I use circular buffer to implement it. My initial thought is :

```
 int dequeue(queue_t* q, int* val) {
   if(q->size==0){
   printf("Queue is Empty\n");
   return QUEUE_IS_EMPTY;
}
else {
   printf("Dequeueing\n");
   q->size--;
   q->front++;
   if (q->front == q->capacity)
   {
      q->front = 0;
   }
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

I wonder it is a mistake like copy paste or sth ?

Comment: How can we know? We can only guess, this question is too broad. You don't provide an [mcve]. We don't know about `queue_t`.

Comment: Your code example doesn't return any value from the queue, so my guess would be that you need to return the actual dequeued value through the `int* val` parameter, and return the status result. Also, if this is a circular buffer, then `q->size` is redundant (and will make problems with concurrent access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `dequeue` is probably for telling whether or not the function successfully dequeued some data while `val` is supposed to hold the dequeued data (if any).

Assuming that your queue has an array `data` holding the `int`values, it could be like:

```
int dequeue(queue_t* q, int* val) 
{
   if(q->size==0){
     printf("Queue is Empty\n");
     return QUEUE_IS_EMPTY;
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("Dequeueing\n");

      *val = q->data[q->front];   // Here you set the data value

      q->size--;
      q->front++;
      if (q->front == q->capacity)
      {
         q->front = 0;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Then it can be used like:

```
int d;
if (dequeue(myQueue, &d) != QUEUE_IS_EMPTY)
{
   printf("dequeued value is %d\n", d);
}
else
{
   printf("not data available\n");
}
```